# useEffect doesn't listen localStorage due to react-query

Tags: reactjs, local-storage

```
import SignInButton from "../UI/SignInButton/SignInButton";
import ProfileBar from "../UI/ProfileBar/ProfileBar";
import SignUpButton from "../UI/SignUpButton/SignUpButton";
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";


const Header = () => {
  const [isLogin, setIsLogin] = useState<boolean>(
    !!localStorage.getItem("access"),
  );

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleStorageChange() {
      setIsLogin(!!localStorage.getItem("access"));
    }

    window.addEventListener("storage", handleStorageChange);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("storage", handleStorageChange);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <>
      <header className='sticky top-0 z-30'>
        <div
          className='
            flex justify-between px-12 max-xl:px-8 bg-t-header-bottom h-[70px] items-center max-md:px-4 border-b-2 border-b-t-header-bottom-border
          '
        >
          <div className='flex items-center max-lg:hidden'>
            {isLogin ? (
              <ProfileBar />
            ) : (
              <div className='flex gap-3'>
                <SignInButton />
                <SignUpButton />
              </div>
            )}
          </div>
        </div>
      </header>
    </>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

here I'm trying to make useEffect react to changes in localStorage and everything works, but only when I delete values from localStorage manually

```
import { useLogout } from "src/hooks/AuthHooks";

const ProfileBar = () => {
  const logout = useLogout();

  return (
    <div className='text-t-text-primary' onClick={() => logout.mutateAsync()}>
      Logout
    </div>
  );
};

export default ProfileBar;
```

the component in which useLogout is called

```
export function useLogout() {
  return useMutation(() => AuthService.logout(), {
    onSuccess: () => {
      localStorage.removeItem("access");
      localStorage.removeItem("refresh");
    },
    onError: (data) => console.log(data),
  });
}
```

onSuccess is triggered and I can even see how access and refresh are removed from localStorage, but the useEffect no longer responds to this

Comment: The storage event doesn't fire at all while you are in the same window. It will fire on every window other than the active one that has caused the changes to localstorage and share the origin with the window that acts as source of changes. In general, there's no such event that would allow you to listen to localstorage changes caused from the window you are in at the moment.

Comment: Thanks to above comment, I also get it. Check this out: [Window: storage event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/storage_event). I think you should manage your `isLogin` state with another way(ex. set state from mutation callback), not with storage event listener. Or manage it with both ways.

Comment: thanks for your answer guys, I think then I’ll just store this variable in some state manager where I’ll also add information about the user that comes in